そんな VS その - category VS specific
そんな is often translated in bilingual dictionaries (such as jisho) with expressions along the lines of "such, that sort of, that kind of".
This suggests to me that そんな literally refers to entire categories, not just individual entities. In English, if I say: "Such mistakes are common", the statement isn't just about one individual mistake, but refers to a whole class of similar mistakes that get grouped together by the speaker, allowing him to make a more general statement.
I've noticed that in Japanese it's not uncommon to say things like そんなことをしないでください。I think in English one would normally just say: "Please don't do that."
I think that maybe this is due to a general cognitive preference that the Japanese have to make  general statements in situations where an English speaker would go for a more specific statement. I'd like to hear your thoughts on this.
Either way, sometimes I come across more extreme examples, such as in this video. At 2:00, the speaker refers back to Ken-san (which he just described as looking happy - 嬉しそうな顔をしています) by saying:

ハナさんとユキさんがそんな嬉しそうなケンさんについて話をしています。

Later in the same video, at 3:10, when the speaker moves on to another situation also involving Ken-san, he says:

はい、そんなケンさんですが、ケンさんは英語がペラペラです。ペラペラというのは上手に話すことが出来ます。そして、またハナさんとユキさんが噂話をしています。[...]

In both instances, the statements are very specifically referring to Ken-san and they don't seem to possibly apply to any other "such" person.
Could you explain why そんな was used instead of, say, その?

This is a very natural way of expressing things in Japanese.  In these contexts, saying そんな sounds much more natural than その.  My intuition as a nonnative speaker is that その would just pick out Ken.  But that idea being expressed is something about Ken's nature, who he is.  In such instances そんな has a broader sense and range of application.
You listed three translation for そんな but are only focusing on "such".  You also left off "like that".  Keep in mind these meanings.
Think of そんなケン as meaning something more like "The Ken who is like that".
These quantifiers starting with こ, そ, and あ have much broader use than their meanings might suggest.
In the quoted context you provided,

はい、そんなケンさんですが、ケンさんは英語がペラペラです。ペラペラというのは上手に話すことが出来ます。
Yes, there's the Ken who is like that, but... Ken is fluent in English.  To say "fluent", he is able to speak very well.....

Think about this a bit in English.  If you keep referring to someone as "that Ken", it's going to sound odd or like there's something perhaps unsavory or peculiar about him.  The same thing happens in Japanese.
Now, if you were talking about multiple Kens or there was uncertainty about who Ken is, you might use そのケン, a bit like "that Ken!
Recall that こ, そ, and あ can indicate proximity to the two speakers. So, そのケン might also sound like, "the Ken you were just talking about".  Or, given the context of Ken just getting a new girlfriend, そのケン might sound like saying "your Ken" (as in "he's your boyfriend").  But in this situation there is no ambiguity of who Ken is.  It seems clear that he's neither Hana's or Yuki's boyfriend.
Saying そのケン selects Ken out for particular attention here.  That's not what's happening here.
Ken is being discussed and why he's so happy.  Whether you want to call it nature (you seem to construe "nature" as indicating a more permanent character trait, I'm not meaning it that way) or state of mind, that's the focus of all the gossip about Ken.  So, you're not going to be talking about "that Ken", そのケン, but rather "Ken who's like that [ie, got a new girlfriend]",　そんなケン.

Thank you for your answer! I marked it as useful, but this usage is still not entirely clear to me.
Of the 4 translations on Jisho, I'd say the first 3 hint at categorical meaning, and the 4th one (like that) itself is often used to express sth very similar.
I can see how "The Ken who is like that" is different - basically a way to refer back to the previous description about Ken. But in what situations is this preferred over その? The first statement refers to Ken's temporary state - looking happy because of his new girlfriend, so the usage doesn't seem limited to describing one's nature.

@DavideBordoni - The first statement can be understood as talking about そんな様子のケンさん.

Thank you for the update! The first situation is very clear to me now but  I don't think this applies at 3:10.
When he says そんなケンさんですが [...] the previous characterization of Ken (as looking happy and having a girlfriend) is entirely irrelevant to this new situation. そんな just seems to tell us that it's the same person that was mentioned earlier. It's not about his nature / state of mind / 様子 (as aguijonazo-san suggested) or any physical or psychological characterization. Do you think the speaker is wrong for using it? I'm not saying he couldn't be, even natives make mistakes sometimes.
